# Laravel - delete password value from request when form is not validated

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm using FormRequest validation in my Laravel controller method. I'm validating (beside others) fields 'password' and 'password_confirmation'. The rules are:

```
$rules['password'] = 'required|string|min:8|required_with:password_confirmation';
$rules['password_confirmation'] = 'min:8|required_with:password|same:password';
```

(I'm not using 'confirmed', because the validation message is always only on the first field, not on the confirmation one)

When the password confirmation does not match thus the validation fails all data does get returned to the form, including the passwords. Is there some way to exclude them from returning only in case of failed validation - so that the user has to manually input them again? I presume it has to be done somewhere in the custom FormValidation class, probably overriding one of its methods - however, how would I go about it? Just delete it from the returning array?

Answer (score 0):

in the password fields of your `register.blade.php`, remove the `old('password')` from the `value` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, I'm using vue.js on the front-end so I have to somehow not send the value at all from backend, thus doing it in FormRequest is what came to mind